# Restarting multiple services script

Tags: bash, shell

The systems admin are preventing me from restarting multiple services `sudo systemctl restart service1 service2`.

Is there a way to get around this with a bash script.

Comment: Well scripts won't have more rights than you, so I guess the answer is no.

Comment: Can you restart a single one?

Comment: yes I can restart a single one. `sudo systemctl restart service1` works but when i do multiple it doesnt.

Comment: I didn't think a script would have more rights but I wasn't certain.

Comment: If you have permissions to do them all individually but can't do them all in one command then 1) is that valid syntax for your OS & version? 2) if the admins somehow disallowed it, maybe you should reconsider your methodology... and 3) you could just do them in a loop, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file e.g.: `touch ~/restart.sh`

Make it executable e.g.: `chmod 775 ~/restart.sh`

Put the following code inside:

```
#!/bin/sh
for service; do systemctl restart "$service"; done
```

Run it with `sudo ~/restart.sh service1 service2`

Comment: You mistyped the `do; ` with semicolon and you don't need to iterate over services, you can just `systemctl restart "$@"`

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for spotting the typo. The question was about the fact that `systemctl restart service1 service2` does not work on his system.